# Mysqli stmt num_rows always 0

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I think everything is ok. Mail stored in DB but the output is 0. Where i am wrong ?

```
class connection {
    private $mail;
    private $conn;
    function connect() {
        $this->conn = new mysqli ('**','**','**','**');
    }
    function control () {
        $this->mail = 'aa@a.com';
        $checkmail = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = ?';
        if ($stmt = $this->conn->prepare($checkmail)) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $this->mail);
            $stmt->execute;
            $stmt->store_result();
            $count = $stmt->num_rows;
            echo $count;
        }
    }
}
$a = new connection();
$a->connect();
$a->control();
```

Thank you for reply.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson `mysqli_stmt` has it also, available after `store_result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php) is a method:

```
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

When dealing with a program, you are supposed to always have error reporting on.
On a development PC it's all right to have them shown right in the browser, while on a production server you have to check error log for them.

Just because

```
Notice: Undefined property: mysqli_stmt::$execute in ...
```

error message is clear and unambiguous.